# UWP custom control template not applied (but only in one project)

Tags: xaml, uwp, controltemplate

I have created a custom version of the [default UWP button control template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299109.aspx), which simply modifies the color scheme of the disabled state.

In a test project this customization is applied correctly, but in my real project it is ignored (although other custom control templates are applied correctly).

I have searched the project for `TargetType="Button"`, hoping to discover something else that is overriding or interfering with this custom template, but there is nothing unusual; just a few style definitions that are setting properties for specific button instances.

Can anyone suggest why a custom UWP control template would be ignored or how I can debug what's causing this?

Comment: Can you post your template here?

Comment: @TastesLikeTurkey: the template is identical to the default template (linked above) but with a single color change to the background color in the disabled state.

Comment: @TimCoulter I cannot reproduce this issue. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Do you write it in Generic?